# Auto lower case for JavaScript bot

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a bot that will convert all the uppercase into lowercase. I want to verify if I am doing it right and in an efficient way.

```
var temp = /^[a-z][^a-z]*$/;
fb.onMessage(function (msg) {
    var parts = msg['m'].split(" ");
    var cleaned = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var word = parts[i];
        if (temp.test(word)) {
            cleaned.push(word);
        } else {
            cleaned.push(word.toLowerCase());
        }
    }
    msg['m'] = cleaned.join(' ');

    return msg;
});
```

Comment: Can you post an example of input and output?

Comment: Why even check for lowercase, just convert everything to lowercase

Comment: Something like HELLO -> hello

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to split the string up, simply use [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) on the complete string. `toLowerCase` does not care about parts being lowercase already, or parts not being alpha characters.

Comment: seems that OP does not want to lowercase URLs and other stuff

Answer (score 0):

Are the messages extremely lengthy?

It would probably be just as efficient, if not more so, to simply lowercase all of the words without first checking a pattern. Also, there is no reason to lowercase the words after the fact.

If I'm reading what you wrote up there, you are splitting, checking if it is already lowercase, if not, making it lowercase, then adding all the words back together. It'd be far simpler and faster to just do it all in one go.

```
fb.onMessage(function (msg) {
    msg.m = msg.m.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    return msg;
});
```

I threw in a `replace(/\s+/g, '')` which would collapse any multiple space sections to a single space. Not sure if this is part of what you were trying to attempt above or not. If you don't care about that, remove the replace for an event more efficient command.

Comment: Just to note. TimWolla switched `msg['m']` to `msg.m`. While that is typically how I'd create mine as well, they are essentially synonymous. The only time I've ever seen having to choose one over another is if you were using TypeScript and it didn't know the context of msg, it would throw a compiler error on `msg.m` but not `msg['m']`.